# Class List treated as if global

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class City(Object):
    symbol = "1"
    name = "City"
    priority = 30 # Should actually be above mob layer.
    size = 5

    starting_citizens = 5
    citizens = []

    resources = {"food" : 100,
                 "wood" : 0,
                 "iron" : 0}

    inventory = []

    needs_processing = True
    action_time = 6

    def __init__(self, loc, x, y):
        global log
        log = log + "A new town has been settled!\n"
        self.name = self.name + " " + str(random.randrange(1, 999))
        super().__init__(loc, x, y)
        print(len(self.citizens))
        print("Procedure undergoing in: " + self.name)
        for N in range(self.starting_citizens - 1):
            print("Another one bites the city")
            self.add_citizen(Peasant)
        print("CITY INIT END")
        print(len(self.citizens))
        print(self.citizens)

    def add_citizen(self, citizen_type):
        print("Procedure undergoing in: " + self.name)
        print(str(len(self.citizens)) + " before adding occured")
        self.citizens.append(citizen_type(self, -2, -2)) #Huehuehue. -2 -2 won't be qdeled.
        print(str(len(self.citizens)) + " after adding occured")
```

For any amount of reasons, all class City objects share the citizens list. It is identical in each one, what is not something I would like. I would like to have each Class have it's own list.

No amount of debugging helped me see the problem.

http://prntscr.com/kgz5as

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: But there's nothing wrong with the identation.

Comment: @LudwigVonChesterfield yes, because someone actually fixed it for you, check the edit log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you defined your `citizens` list to be a class variable instead of an instance variable. It is therefore being shared between all instances. (See 9.3.5 in the [Docs page on classes](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html))

You actually have multiple variables that should probably be instance variables instead of being shared by all isntances of the class (like `citizens`, `size`, `name` etc.). Define them as isntance variables instead like so:

```
def __init__(self, loc, x, y):
    self.citizens = []
```

Comment: I haven't actually thought about this. Thank you much!

Comment: Actually, now that I think of it. Would doing something along the lines of self.citizens = self.citizens initiate it properly?

Comment: Would probably have to be something like `self.citizens = self.citizens[:]` as mentioned in Reblochon Masque' answer but what would be the sense in having a citizens list as a class variable in the first place. Shouldn't it be something that is specific to every city? So it would sense to just create a new list (or initialize it with some list of citizens passed to the init function)

Comment: I was asking because of wishing to make size an instance variable, which initiates with a value given in class.

Comment: Sou you want every city to start with `starting_citizen` many citizens?

Comment: No, what do you mean? I was talking about applying the value given in class in init to size. As in, I define size in class, and then in instance I give it that value.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood your point with the `size` as instance variable. So you want to define self.size in your `__init__` function and initialize it as a value that is set as a class variable?

Comment: Yes. Would I need to make a seperate variable like init_size to do that?

Comment: You could have it as an optional parameter to your `__init__` function: `def __init__(self, loc, x, y, init_size=5)`. If not specified, then init_size will be 5. If you want a city with a different size, you can create it with `City(loc, x,y, init_size=<whatever>`

Comment: I actually can't, City is a subtype of an object, which has just so many variables, and I would be getting errors when trying to initialise Cities elsewhere. As you didn't specify any other options, I most likely will have a seperate variable. Thank you for your input!